# How to rename a header to a csv file using python and adding numeric value on that column?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, header

I'm pretty new with Python programming and would like to seek your expertise/help on how to achieve my goal.

So far, what I have done is to delete unnecessary columns from a CSV file using Python. Now, I want to rename a specific Header "Tags" into "Quantity" on the edited CSV file. I also want to append the value of that column since it's blank and make every cell into "1".

Below is the Python Script I have so far. Looking forward to your suggestions. Thank you very much!

```
import os
import pandas as pd

directory = 'path/'
ext = ('.csv')

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    f = os.path.join(directory, filename)

if f.endswith(ext):

    head_tail = os.path.split(f)
    head_tail1 = 'path/Output'
    k =head_tail[1]
    r=k.split(".")[0]

    p=head_tail1 + "/" + r + " - Output.csv"

    mydata = pd.read_csv(f)

    new =mydata[["Part ID","Serial ID","Bin","Cluster","Site","Room","Model MPN","Vendor","Type","State","Tags"]]
    new.to_csv(p ,index=False)
```

I have Googled and Youtubed possible solutions but it doesn't work and faced errors in Pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

```
new = mydata[["Part ID","Serial ID","Bin","Cluster","Site","Room","Model MPN","Vendor","Type","State","Tags"]]

# added lines
new = new.rename(columns={'Tags': 'Quantity'})
new['Quantity'] = 1

new.to_csv(p ,index=False)
```

This should work.

Comment: Hi JayPeerachai, thank you for answering fast. Followed your solution and unfortunately it does nothing to my edited CSV file. Can you tell me where should I put the code please? What I did is I added it at the bottom after new.to_csv(p ,index=False). Thank you so much!

Comment: I updated my answer, let try there.

Comment: Hi @JayPeerachai, seeking for your expertise again. I want to merge 3 columns into 1 column, basically from my script, Site,Room and Bin will be in 1 column. What I did is below and its giving me error: Appreciate your help!                                                                                 new =mydata[["Site","Room","Bin","Bin ID"]]
        new = new.rename(columns={'Bin ID': 'Qty. of Parts'})
        new['Qty. of Parts'] = 1
        df = pd.DataFrame()
        df['Bin Name'] = df['Site'] + df['Room'] + df['Bin']
        new.to_csv(p ,index=False)

Comment: what was the error? actually, you should open the new question

Comment: I have open a question about this, "Concatenate Columns in CSV file using Python and Count the total per Uniqueid". Basically I want to merge 3 Columns into 1 Column and all of its data be will be concatenated as well. I just need the script to achieve that. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JMC I have answered you in your new question: "Concatenate Columns in CSV file using Python and Count the total per Uniqueid". Pls check. Also, don't forget to accept my answer in this question first.